# WPF DataGrid CellEditEnding - DataSet Not Updating Till Row Lost Focus

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I need to be able to update values of a dataset once a cell loses focus from editing.  I know when the cell loses focus (CellEditEnding), but problem is, the actual updating of it's context item does not occur till focus on that row actually occurs.  This becomes a huge issue when there is only one item left, since it may never lose focus.

How do I make sure that each time a column edit is complete (CellEditEnding), the actual context for that row is updated at that point (not just when the row loses focus)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since this is a touch screen app, I was able to apply this by setting focus to a hidden item any time the mouse hovers over any other item (touch began)... However a less hackish approach is appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

I met a similar problem, I have a DataGrid row that contains 5 columns.
The data from the 5 columns will be updated in source only after the entire datagrid row has lost focus.

After some search, I found an easy way to do it.
That is to add "UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus" in your databinding in the cell.

For example:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataSets}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

This will do the trick, so when each of the cell lost focus, instead of the entire row, the data from the cell will update the source immediately.

Comment: also you can change it to: SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" it works for me .. thanx :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`DataGrid.CommitEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.commitedit%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) from your [`DataGrid.CellEditEnding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending.aspx) handler, being sure to handle reentrancy.

Here's a blog article that describes the technique:

- [Commiting bound cell changes immediately in WPF Datagrid](http://codefluff.blogspot.com/2010/05/commiting-bound-cell-changes.html)

Comment: even using the code you mentioned, the first row I've started to edit, remained on EditMode, and I couldn't edit different row to edit.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and none of the "usual" fixes worked...

What worked for me was to use the overloaded version of `CommitEdit()` as follows

```
DataGrid1.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply jump to any other control of your dialog by calling [control].**Focus()**. Do this inside the **OnClosing**() event.

The LostFocus is the default update trigger for the data cell. But the window itself and also the border or title of the window (and there the system button "X") cannot get a focus. That's why the editing is not end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the any PreviewMouseMove event from any other object.
In my case I want the datagrid to loose control, before adding a new line to it.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void MenuItem_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid.CommitEdit();
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
 <MenuItem Header="New Line" Command="{Binding CommandNewRow}" PreviewMouseMove="MenuItem_PreviewMouseMove"/>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
    public ICommand CommandNewRow
    {
        get
        {
            if (_commandNewRow == null)
            {
                _commandNewRow = new RelayCommand(p => CommandNewRowExecute(), p => CommandNewRowCanExecute());
            }
            return _commandNewRow;
        }
    }

    private void CommandNewRowExecute()
    {
       FileList.Add(new File("", ""));
    }

    private bool CommandNewRowCanExecute()
    {
        if (FileList.Count > 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```