# in WPF DataGrid how to force lost focus (and thereby commit) of a datagrid row when rightclicking outside it

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid with cells that can be edited. When the row loses focus the property changed event fires and I handle that by committing the changes to an entity object and eventually to the database.
The user can rightclick outside of the datagrid and select from a context menu. Some of the context menu items are dependent on the data in the datagrid (to be precise they are dependent on the committed data).
However, the problem is that a rightclick outside the DataGrid does not remove the focus from the DataGrid. This means the changes to the current row are not committed. This means the user gets surprised because the menu item commands works on data that are different from what is shown on the screen.
I realize that this is how the DataGrid works. However, I also realize the the users will never be able to understand this.

So how can I solve this? Can I force a lost focus when rightclicking? Or is there some special property on the DataGrid I can use?

(I found this: [WPF DataGrid CellEditEnding - DataSet Not Updating Till Row Lost Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246452/wpf-datagrid-celleditending-dataset-not-updating-till-row-lost-focus) which makes the DataGrid commit on a per-cell basis instead of a per-row basis, but it does not solve my problem, since the user still can lose some data (although just one cell instead of a whole row))

Comment: Does [Keyboard.ClearFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.clearfocus.aspx) or focusing the Window in [PreviewMouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown.aspx) help?

Answer (score 3):

I used LPL's suggestions, and created an eventhandler:

```
 private void ViewUserControl_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {            
            // The purpose of this is to make sure that before the context menu on the outer datagrid is run, the row in the inner datagrid is committed (otherwise we might create orders with different quantities than what the user sees on the screen)
            Keyboard.ClearFocus();
        }
```

This solved the problem.