# Implementing two-way DataGrid data binding without using MVVM

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I'll try to put this as clearly as I can, but I'm all too aware that I may be asking the wrong question.  I have a datagrd in WPF (.NET 4.0), which I bind to a datatable in a dataset.  The relevant code-behind (running on window load) is:

```
// create a connection to Top Trumps database
String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csTopTrumps"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs);

// create a new dataset
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

// open the connection (not strictly necessary, as the
// data adapter will do this when you use it anyway)
cn.Open();

// fill data table called Cards with contents of tblCard
SqlDataAdapter daCards = new SqlDataAdapter();
daCards.SelectCommand =
new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblCard ORDER BY CardTitle", cn);
daCards.Fill(ds, "Cards");

// now set the data context for the entire window
this.DataContext = ds;
```

My datagrid definition begins:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[Cards]}"
```

All of that works fine, and I understand it.  I now want to make the data-binding two way, so that changes made in the datagrid will update back to the underlying database.  I know that one way I can do this is by getting at the values of changed rows and using a tableadapter with an Update method to write any changes made back to the underlying database (perhaps on something like the SelectedCellsChanged event, or similar).  However, any approach like this is difficult to implement, because getting at cell values in code-behind in WPF is difficult (and my understanding is that this is the wrong way to go, as I should be using the WPF framework, so help me).

So ... how can I set two-way data-binding to do the work for me?  I've seen people mention setting datagrid properties like:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

but I don't understand how I could get this to work with data adapters and datasets.  What I don't want is any solution involving MVVM or models, as I'm not using these (and yes, I probably should be, I know).  I also want to avoid reams of complicated C# code, involving observable collections, recursive searches through the control hierarchy to find parents and suchlike.

I've searched for a long time, and I THINK what I'm asking does exist - if not, please tell me it doesn't, and apologies for wasting your time, gentle reader!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, a bit late, I think I have the answer I wanted.  The datagrid is bound to a data table (in my instance).  This means you can get at the selected item (which is the row a user double-clicked on, perhaps), turn it into a datarow and then get at the field you're interested in.

```
private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

{

```
// turn the datagrid selected "item" into a data row
DataRowView dr = dg.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

// get at the value for any field (here it's the one called CARD) in the underlying datatable
string CardTitle = (string)dr["Card"];

// display it ...
MessageBox.Show("You are on card " + CardTitle);
```

}

This will solve the problem of double-clicking on a row in a datagrid, and is what I had in mind.  If you're using classes, you can cast the selected item into the relevant object, and get at its properties.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I quite didn't understand you. You wish to avoid WPF framework(observable collection, bindings, recursive searches etc) yet you want to find a way how to do it with using WPF framework.

First you need those functions:

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
       if (child != null)
       {
           break;
       }
   }
       return child;
}

public static DataGridRow GetSelectedRow(this DataGrid grid)
{
    return (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem);
}
public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    if (row == null)
    {
        // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
        grid.UpdateLayout();
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }
    return row;
}

public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
{
    if (row != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

        if (presenter == null)
        {
            grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
            presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
        }

        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        return cell;
    }
    return null;
}

public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, int row, int column)
{
    DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.GetRow(row);
    return grid.GetCell(rowContainer, column);
}
```

Now the DataGrid actually has almost useful event. It's called CellEditEnding. 
Hook it up

```
private bool isManualEditCommit;
private void yourHandler(
  object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e) 
{
 if (!isManualEditCommit) 
 {
  isManualEditCommit = true;
  DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
  grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
  isManualEditCommit = false;
 } else {
    /* you can write foreach loop that would loop through all the DataGridCells
      with DataGridCell cell = grid.GetCell(row, col),
      you can recieve value like GetVisualChild<TextBlock>(cell).Text
      and update everything when you're at last value */
 }
}
```

also read this; [WPF DataGrid CellEditEnding - DataSet Not Updating Till Row Lost Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246452/wpf-datagrid-celleditending-dataset-not-updating-till-row-lost-focus)

This was the hard way, but if you're experienced, you can provide a lot nicer code. 
Try searching terms data binding, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn, two-way binding, cellEditEnding.

Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks for this.  I'll try this out on Friday when I'm next in the office.  Believe me I've searched for all of the things you mention (I already know WinForms and ASP.NET, but am struggling to find the WPF way forward).  Will add another comment when had a chance to look at this.

Comment: This is every bit as complicated as I'd feared.  Why can't I just use:

 private void dg_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            // create pointer to current data row
            DataRowView dr = dg.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            
            // show the column bound to CardTitle field
            MessageBox.Show(dr["CardTitle"].ToString());
}

It seems to work (gives the field value); why is this approach not a good one?