# DataTable did not refresh when it is bound to DataGrid using updatesourcetrigger=PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which has three columns and it is bound to a DataTable.
I need to write some description in the third column of the datagrid and then write the changes of the rows back into the database.
The DataTable does only refresh when I move my selection to the next line of the datagrid. If a row is selected and the third item is changed without moving to the next line the DataTable source doesnt change the item immediately.

Edit: Apply the solution of Geert will solve the problem or simply put the command button to the same layout where the datagrid is.

XAML:

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Width="Auto"
                          Height="Auto"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Broadcasters, Mode=TwoWay}">

                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"
                                        Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=SEN_ID}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sendername"
                                        Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=SEN_NAME}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rabattvergabe"
                                        Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=Rabatt, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
```

Property in ViewModel:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the property value.
    /// </summary>
    public DataTable Broadcasters
    {
        get { return GetValue<DataTable>(BroadcastersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BroadcastersProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register the Broadcasters property so it is known in the class.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly PropertyData BroadcastersProperty =
        RegisterProperty("Broadcasters", typeof(DataTable), null);
```

Save Command:

```cs
/// <summary>
    /// Gets the name command.
    /// </summary>
    public Command SaveCmd { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to invoke when the name command is executed.
    /// </summary>
    private void exec_SaveCmd()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.Broadcasters != null)
            {
                DataRow[] rows = Broadcasters.Select("Rabatt='1'");
                //Do some work to save the result.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Fatal("exec_SaveCmd(): " + ex.Message + ", StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this hasn't to do with Catel, but with the DataGrid behavior.

See this question (+ answer) for more information:

[WPF DataGrid CellEditEnding - DataSet Not Updating Till Row Lost Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246452/wpf-datagrid-celleditending-dataset-not-updating-till-row-lost-focus)